# NullPointerException (@MessageProcessor$MenuMonitor:onOpened:-1) {main}

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Anyone else getting this error in their Google Analytics?

It seems to be newly happening in my apps, I haven't made any major changes in a while, so I am a bit puzzled.

NullPointerException (@MessageProcessor$MenuMonitor:onOpened:-1) {main}

Any help would be great.

Thanks